# Fixing the width of the table being binded in the datagrid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I am working on a windows application.

I am binding a column of a table from the database in a datagrid.But when it is populated its getting its actual dimention and some space is left blank in the datagrid...is it possible that the column of the table would rather take the actual full dimention of the datagrid while populating.

Waiting for your reply...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [`AutoSizeColumnsMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autosizecolumnsmode.aspx) property of the `DataGridView` to `Fill`.

The `DataGridViewColumn` also has an [`AutoSize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.autosizemode.aspx) property, so you can set the behavior for each column individually if you want to have them sized differently.